# dompdf watermark, image, header and footer issues

Tags: php, footer, watermark, dompdf

i am using dompdf as a plugin in codeigniter. it generates the pdf perfectly. but some problem are eating up me for some days.

1. I want to put an image as header in every page of the generated pdf. i did it according to the tutorial given [here](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/FAQ). 
   but no progress. i tried for images of all types(jpg,png,gif) in the same folder wheresript for pdf resides. it did not work. then i tried for setting the path variable for image and css as shown at `http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/Usage` .but i could not get a good example or tutorial for that. if any body has ever used this please help me.
2. i also want to add watermark on every page. for that i am using

   `$pdf->page_text(110, $h - 240,  "TRIAL", Font_Metrics::get_font("verdana", "bold"),110, array(0.92, 0.92, 0.92), 0, -58);`.

This works fine and generates watermark.but watermark comes over content.is there any thing to change the opacity of watermark. it is not changed by changing parameters in array.

3.at the end of every page ( except the last one) i want to put the text "**continued..**". for that i am using

```
$text = "Continued..";
  $width = Font_Metrics::get_text_width($text, $font, $size);
  $pdf->page_text($w - 16 - $width - 38, $y-15, $text, $font, $size, $color);
```

it puts the text in every page(as it should). is there any way to put text in all pages except the last one?

1. how to set font which are not available in the lib file of dompdf?

Comment: if any body has answer to any of the questions please help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) What, exactly, is the code you're using? It sounds like you're having success with inline script, just not images. So there could be a problem with your code.

2) This is a problem with inline script. It is rendered after the HTML content meaning it displays on top of the HTML content. There used to be an opacity option when adding text via inline scripting, but I'm not sure it was ever working correctly. It has been removed from the 0.6.0 code base.

You may have to wait for the next release, which will include more styling options that would enable what you want to do in HTML (specifically, fixed positioning and CSS translate).

3) I'm not sure you can display a header on every page but the last. There is an option to stop an object from displaying, but it appears to only affect subsequent pages. So you'd have to add the relevant code to the page prior to the last page.

4) If you want to add a font you need to be able to parse it using load_font.php. You will also need access to the executable ttf2afm (dompdf 0.5.1) or ttf2ufm (dompdf 0.6.0). There are [instructions on how to load fonts](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/Installation), or you can also try a [web-based font prep tool](http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/load_font.php) I developed.

Comment: @Brian, thanks. yes i am using the inline php script. half an hour before i could get over the opacity issue by doing the following.

Comment: i added two more parameters in the function given below at around 685 line in cpdf_Adapter.cls.php and passing the same in the calling function. function page_text($x, $y, $text, $font, $size, $color = array(0,0,0),
                     $adjust = 0, $angle = 0,  $blend ="Normal", $opacity =1.0) {
        $this->_page_text[] = compact("x", "y", "text", "font", "size", "color", "adjust", "angle", "blend", "opacity");
  } .header img is not coming in every pg(comes in last pg only). for point 3 can u plz say how to get total pg count and current pg# .so that i can compare and do.or post a method

Comment: @Brian for image i am using 

if ( isset($pdf) ) {
 
  $path = base_url();//base path is set to the base directory as in codeigniter config
  $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
  $dompdf ->set_base_path($path);
  $basepath=$dompdf->get_base_path();
  
  $img_w = 1.5 * 72; // 1.5 inches, in points
  $img_h = 0.9 * 72; // 0.9 inch, in points -- change these as required
  $pdf->image( $basepath."path_to_folder/logo.png", "png", 30, 30, $img_w, $img_h);
} in this case image is coming in last page only.my requirement is for all page

Comment: It's been a while since I tried anything with text transparency. It looks like this option has been removed from the 0.6.0 code base, but I'm not sure why. Something we'll have to investigate further and potentially put back in.

Comment: $pdf->get_page_number() = current page; $pdf->get_page_count() = total number of pages

Comment: Where is your inline script located? Adding page text using $pdf->page_text() is a global setting. But when adding script-generated headers/footers it is a relative setting. So if your script is at the end of the page then the headers/footers will only show up at the end. Place your inline script at the beginning of your document and your headers/footers should appear on all pages.

Comment: @Brian thanks genius. your script at the top of page worked fine. to compare page num and count i used  $count=$pdf->get_page_count();
 $pgnum=$pdf->get_page_number(); . but in both the cases i get 1, though my total pages are 5. so it is not printing 'continued..' at all for my script. can u plz show a working piece of code which print on every page but the last.

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to add your "continued" text using headers generated via inline script. The script is run where it is encountered in the document and dompdf doesn't know how many pages exist at the top of the document (so the `get_page_count()` function isn't all that helpful here). You would have to know which page is the next before last, like in [this sample HTML document](http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/debug_tests/so4862417.htm)

Comment: I'd like to think there may be a way using the 0.6.0 release and CSS, but I don't have a solution right now. You could fake it by covering your "continued" text with a rectangle. See [this sample HTML document](http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/debug_tests/so4862417-2.htm) (it's a bit overkill on the rectangle, but you get the idea).

Comment: hi @Brian, with your help everything works fine in local system. but a problem kills in the server. please see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922213/error-in-pdf-image-using-dompdf

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that **DOMPDF_ENABLE_PHP is set to true** in dompdf_config.inc.php ~line 173 in 0.6.2
Be aware that this is a potential security risk if there is any unfiltered content coming from an untrusted source to the pdf.

```
/**
 * Enable inline PHP
 *
 * If this setting is set to true then DOMPDF will automatically evaluate
 * inline PHP contained within <script type="text/php"> ... </script> tags.
 *
 * Enabling this for documents you do not trust (e.g. arbitrary remote html
 * pages) is a security risk.  Set this option to false if you wish to process
 * untrusted documents.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define("DOMPDF_ENABLE_PHP", true);
```