# error in pdf image using dompdf

Tags: image, pdf, dompdf

I have to display a logo in every page of a generated PDF.  Though it works fine in the local system, it throws following exception in the server:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDFlibException' with message 'Handle parameter or option of type 'image' has bad value 0' in /var/www/dev/subdomains/rfqms/httpdocs/sprintnineteen/system/plugins/dompdf/include/pdflib_adapter.cls.php:664 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/dev/subdomains/rfqms/httpdocs/sprintnineteen/system/plugins/dompdf/include/pdflib_adapter.cls.php(664): PDFlib->fit_image(0, 30, 746, 'boxsize={86 43}...') #1 /var/www/dev/subdomains/rfqms/httpdocs/sprintnineteen/system/plugins/dompdf/include/php_evaluator.cls.php(66) : eval()'d code(16): PDFLib_Adapter->image('http://rfqms.de...', 'jpg', 30, 3, 86.4, 43.2) #2 /var/www/dev/subdomains/rfqms/httpdocs/sprintnineteen/system/plugins/dompdf/include/php_evaluator.cls.php(66): eval() #3 /var/www/dev/subdomains/rfqms/httpdocs/sprintnineteen/system/plugins/dompdf/include/php_evaluator.cls.php(70): PHP_Evaluator->evaluate('??//$base_img_u...') #4 /var/www/dev/subdomains/rfqms/httpdocs/sprintnineteen/system/plugins/dompdf/include/renderer.cls.php(180): PHP_Evaluator->render(O in /var/www/dev/subdomains/rfqms/httpdocs/sprintnineteen/system/plugins/dompdf/include/pdflib_adapter.cls.php on line 664
```

After some analysis I found that in local it uses `cpdf_adapter.cls.php` for image, where as in server it uses `pdflib_adapter.cls.php` for image.

I even tried for all the types of images according to:

```
pdfLib tutorial Version 8.0.2 ---page # 166--- Inline images are only supported for imagetype=ccitt, jpeg, and raw. For other image types the inline option will silently be ignored.
```

So, what is the problem that leads to this exception?

**some additional info:**

- local PHP Version 5.3.0
- server PHP Version 5.2.16
- dompdf version 0.5.2
- DOMPDF_TEMP_DIR has r/w/e permission
- local machine is windows vista
- server machine is linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a bug in dompdf at some point related to adding images via PDFLib. I'm not sure if the issue has been addressed yet or not for the upcoming 0.6.0 release. [There is a relevant thread](http://groups.google.com/group/dompdf/browse_thread/thread/21404e12244ba8bd) on the support group. Take a look at my last post there for information on a work-around if you want to continue using PDFLib.

The other option would be to tell dompdf to use CPDF. In dompdf_config.inc.php set `DOMPDF_PDF_BACKEND` to "CPDF" instead of "auto" or "PDFLib".

Comment: thanks boss. i am really grateful to your commitment towards community. any way the above problem is solved after setting DOMPDF_PDF_BACKEND to "CPDF". but it created another problem in server.and the work around solution given in the thread link does not work for me. error is as follows **A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning Message: file_get_contents(http://myurl/logos/logo.png) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Connection timed out Filename: lib/class.pdf.php Line Number: 4334**

Comment: Always glad to help. The message indicates a timeout, is "myurl/logos/logo.png" some placeholder text for the purposes of this post? Have you tried an image from another web site or via the local file system?

Comment: yes myurl/logos/logo.png is the placeholder and i have tried images from local file system. i think this one is only due to incorrect path. though the above url shows the image directly on the browser it does not load it on pdf.

Comment: So the placeholder is a full URL including domain? I'm not sure why DOMPDF would run into a timeout problem if it works in the web browser, unless the server is having trouble looking up the domain. Is the PHP setting allow_url_fopen set to true? Can you try creating a stand-alone PHP script whose sole purpose is to open the file using `file_get_contents()`? This would at least let us know whether it's a dompdf or PHP issue.