# Image is not shown in PDF file using dompdf

Tags: php, html, dompdf

I am using DOMPDF to convert the html into PDF and after converting I'm sending that PDF file to user mail id.

Everything is working perfectly but in PDF file I am not able to see the image of logo of my site. I also searched in stackoverflow for previous question such as :- [error in pdf image using dompdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922213/error-in-pdf-image-using-dompdf) ,
[dompdf and img tag, image wont show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327915/dompdf-and-img-tag-image-wont-show)

I also set `DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE` to `TRUE` and `DOMPDF_PDF_BACKEND` to `CPDF`

my image tag is :-

`<img src="http://www.example.com/clients/myprojects/images/logo.png" alt="" /></a>`

I'm giving full path of my website but still it does not show image in my PDF file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you are still getting the issue in image, then you can debug the issue on this file: vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/Image/Cache.php you will get the understanding from where the issue is occuring.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

use full directory path with .jpg image

Comment: a year back I tried png was not working. so I did with jpg image. not sure current status of the dompdf compatability with png.

Comment: yeah thanks I converted my image to jpg and its working perfectly thanks :)

Comment: @RakeshShetty FYI, dompdf has to do some pre-processing of PNG images to handle transparency. You'll want to make sure GD support is enabled in PHP.

Comment: I can also confirm PNG images do not work properly in v0.5.0, use JPG instead and then there's no problems! Thank you @Rameshkrishnan_S

Comment: if you are still getting the issue in image, then you can debug the issue on this file: vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/Image/Cache.php
you will get the understanding from where the issue is occuring.

Answer (score 4):

It works for me.

```
 <img src="<?php echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/placeholder.jpg';?>"/>
 <img src="<?php echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'\placeholder.jpg';?>"/>
 <img src="<?php echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'./placeholder.jpg';?>"/>
```

Comment: This is the best. I could not grasp that "full path" means "local path" until I see this answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Don't put full path of URL, just put `foldername/filename.jpg`

Example:

```
<img src="uploads/kuruvi.jpg">
```

Answer (score 2):

I my case i spend 2 hour finally i got answer 
img src not working with url or path you should covert it base64 format

```
<?php 
$data = file_get_contents('https://teafloor.com/wp-content/themes/teafloor2-0/assets/images/logo.png');
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
?>
<?php echo '<div class="company-logo">
    <img src="'.$base64.'"  alt="base" />
</div>';
?>
```

or

```
<img src="<?php echo $base64; ?>"  alt="base" />
```

Answer (score 0):

if I recall it correctly you can put there a full system path to that image - absolute or relative to your script

Comment: thank for your reply but absoloute or realtive path doesn't work

Comment: what is your setup? is dompdf on the same server as images you are trying to include?

Answer (score 0):

```
//use full directory path something like this    

    $currentsite = getcwd();
    $html = <<<HTML
    <html>
    <img src="{$currentsite}/sites/all/modules/certificate_handler/image002.png" alt="" /></a>

     </html>
    HTML;
```

Comment: sorry about that. while highlighting as code I missed that line. fixed now :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `alt` attribute and changing it from a self-closing tag (`/>`) to a normal one (`>`). It worked for me.

Note: dompdf seems to have a bad response to any inline styles on `img` tags, so I suggest removing them if you´re using any.

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

```
$imgurl       = $graficas[$i]; 
$path_parts   = pathinfo($imgurl);
$graficas[$i] = $path_parts['filename'].".jpg";
```

And works. I hope this would help you too

Answer (score 0):

DOMPDF

working now with `png,jpg`.

here what I used.

I have `index.php` file in route folder and image in subfolder namely images.

```
$image ="images/".$_FILES['image_index_name']['name'];
$htm= '';
```

Answer (score -1):

You just have to change the line `def("DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE", FALSE);` to `true` in the file `DOMPDF_CONFIG.INC`

Answer (score -2):

Now latest DOMPDF version another, but have the same problem on PHP v5.3

Upgrade to v5.4 or higher

The problem has solved.

Answer (score -4):

I think you could add this

```
private function change_url_image($data,$url){  
$str=$url; //for example "http://localhost/yoursite/";
$str2=str_replace($str,"",$data);
return $str2;
}
```

to change url for image it's very simple

Comment: Very simple answer. Also a very useless one, since you don't explain _how_ to use it. Plus, the whole thing could be simplified to just one line of code, which eliminates the utterly redundant `$str` and equally badly named `$str2`: `return str_replace($url, "", $data)`.